# Another way to redirect output in Bash

Tags: bash, redirect, output

in bash when we want to read file we use the cat command 
 `cat file.txt` 
but if we don't want to use whitespace , we can type: 
`{cat,file.txt}` 
Is there a way to redirect output without using the symbols > or < or & 
i mean is there an equivalent to this command: 
`cat file.txt > /dev/null` 
and Thanks.

Comment: Why would you care about whitespace? I can't really picture a situation where you would ever need `{cat,file.txt}`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish that you can't (or don't want to) use `>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd want to, but you could do:

```
eval {cat,input} "$(echo _/dev/null | tr _ '\076')"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

|tee (called pipe-T) - will redirect output(same as >) to file but also prints at the stdout:

```
cat file.txt|tee outfile.txt
```

|tee -a: will append output to file (same as >>) but also prints at the stdout:

```
cat file.txt|tee -a outfile.txt
```

Comment: ... or `| dd of=outfile.txt`.

Comment: It is inaccurate to say "prints it on console".  It writes the data to the named file as well as to stdout.  That may be an associated tty, but it very often is not. (And it almost certainly is not the console.) Do not conflate stdout with a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `tee` You may use `exec` to redirect the output

```
 exec 3>&1 # making file descriptor 3 to point to 1 where 1 is stdout
 exec 1>fileout #redirecting 1 ie stdout to a file
 {cat,file} # this goes to fileout & question requirement
 exec 1>&3 # restoring 1 to default
 {cat,38682813.c} # This will be printed at the stdout
```